# show null values that does not match with another table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two table "Table A" and "Table B"

Table A is a result of joins with other tables. And Table B is a separate table with having 1 field common in Table A.

Table A:

```
Year   Name  Value
2011   A     Item1
2010   B      1
2011   C     Item2
```

Table B:

```
id   Value
1    Item1
2    Item2
3    Item3
4    Item4
```

I want result to be like:

```
Year   Name  Value
2011   A     Item1
2010   B      NULL
2011   C     Item2
```

My Efforts are:

```
SELECT d.Portfolio,
       d.Name,
       d.AccountName,
       d.CashGAAP,
       d.OriginalDate,
       d.Amount,
       d.AccountNumber,
       d.AttributeSetName,
       d.TheDate,
       d.Year,
       d.Value
FROM (SELECT Portfolio.LegalEntityName AS Portfolio,
             Forecast.Name,
             CoA.AccountName,
             Forecast_Data.CashGAAP,
             CONVERT(DATE, Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS OriginalDate,
             SUM(Forecast_Data.Amount) AS Amount,
             CoA.AccountNumber ,
             Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName,
             '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate)) + '-'
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(Forecast_Data.TheDate)) + '-01' AS TheDate,
             YEAR(Forecast_Data.TheDate) AS Year,
             Forecast_Attribute.Value
FROM Portfolio
     INNER JOIN Forecast ON Portfolio.PortfolioID = Forecast.PortfolioID
     INNER JOIN Forecast_Account 
        ON Forecast.ForecastID = Forecast_Account.ForecastID
     INNER JOIN Forecast_Data 
        ON Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = 
              Forecast_Data.ForecastAccountID
     INNER JOIN CoA ON CoA.AccountNumber = Forecast_Account.AccountNumber
     INNER JOIN Attribute_Set 
        ON CoA.AttributeSetID = Attribute_Set.AttributeSetID
     INNER JOIN Forecast_Attribute 
        ON Forecast_Account.ForecastAccountID = 
              Forecast_Attribute.ForecastAccountID
     WHERE (Forecast.ForecastID = 5)
        OR (Forecast.ForecastID = 6)
     GROUP BY Portfolio.LegalEntityName,
              Forecast.Name,
              CoA.AccountName,
              Forecast_Data.CashGAAP,
              Forecast_Data.TheDate,
              CoA.AccountNumber,
              Attribute_Set.AttributeSetName,
              Forecast_Attribute.Value) 
     AS d
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor ON d.Value = Vendor.VendorName
```

I have renamed the example tables that are explained in Question:

```
Table A = d
Table B = Vendor
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`: `SELECT
  a.year, a.name, b.value
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.value = b.value`.

Comment: @DeepSharma do not use `InnerJoin` it will fetch only matching values .

Comment: inner join is for creating table A. it have no relation with table B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should LEFT JOIN B to the A and show `B.Value` instead of `A.Value` in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT Year, Name, B.Value
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B on A.Value=B.Value
```

Comment: @DeepSharma: "not working" isn't and error :) What error occurs when you run it? Or it isn't show what you expect?

Comment: I am getting values from table A instead of null in result.

Comment: @DeepSharma: You should replace `d.Value` with `Vendor.VendorName` at the first line then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables

You need to apply `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON tableA.Value=tableB.Value;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table (tableA), with the matching rows in the right table (tableB). The result is `NULL` in the right side when there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    A.Year, A.Name, B.Value
from
    A left join B on A.Value= B.value;
```